# Showing content to specific BuddyPress Member Types

Tags: buddypress, membership, members

On my project I'm using BuddyPress [Member Types](https://codex.buddypress.org/developer/member-types/). The problem is I would like to display specific content to each member type. Something like; website checks Member Type based on logged in user id and then it shows a piece of content based on the member type.

Has anyone tried this? If so can you pint me in the right direction?

*Note*
This is a core BuddyPress feature, I will not be using any membership plugins to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is on the [codex page link](https://codex.buddypress.org/developer/member-types/) in your question.

```
// Get the member type of user 5412.
$member_type = bp_get_member_type( 5412 );
```

So you could do something like this:

```
$member_type = bp_get_member_type( get_current_user_id() );
if ( $member_type == 'dog' )
   echo 'Bark';
```